# Allowing a repetitive event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code that commits an action on the screen. However as soon as the event ends I can not repeat the action. I tried attaching `.live()` and `.on()` onto the code but it did not work. I'm at a lost at what event handler I should attach to the selector in order for this to work. The code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#form1').hover(function(){
    $('#button1').css("display", "block");
    $(this).fadeIn(500);
    },
   function(){
    $('#button1').css("display", "none");
    $(this).fadeOut(500);}     
    );


<form action="" id="form1" method="post">
<textarea id="inputbox1"  name="what_i_do"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes. It works once but I want it to happen every time the user moves the mouse over the form

Comment: Not sure if you pasted your code incorrectly but your document.ready isn't closed properly.

Comment: It is closed properly. Just forgot to add it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you hide the element with .fadeOut(), the hover event cannot be triggered anymore, since the element itself is display:none, it cannot magically know where the element is supposed to be.

Instead of using .fadeOut, use .css('opacity', '0'), and create the animation with css3.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#form1').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    },
   function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '0');
   });
});
```

CSS :

```
form {
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;  
   -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;  
}​
```

Here is a jsfiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/F2taJ/

Comment: @jason328 - FYI, this will not provide any animation in any version of IE.  Since jQuery is already present, why not use jQuery animation so that it works in IE too?  This code also loses the hiding and showing of the button that the original code had.

Answer (score 1):

When the mouse leaves, you fadeOut the form with `$(this).fadeOut(500);` which makes it invisible and then there's no way to get the mouse over it again.  You will need to rethink what you're trying to do.

In order for an object to receive mouse events, it can't be `display: none` which is what an object ends up after `fadeOut()`.

You could animate the opacity to zero which makes it invisible, but keeps it's space in the page and it can still get mouse events:

```
$('#form1').hover(function() {
    $('#button1').show();
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
},
function() {
    $('#button1').hide();
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
});
```

I also changed the operations on the button to `.hide()` and `.show()` as they are shortcuts for what you were doing.